# How to redirect to a webpage after WiFi connect

Tags: networking, server, wifi, router

I wanted That Anyone Who connect with Wifi be redirected to a webpage where i show ads

I found That This Can Be Done as follows:
- With Hotspot Router option and DD- WRT and something called
NoCatSplash .
this option would cost me a lot. if I have several branches of my company

How can i do this?? maybe with a proxy server?

thanks.